# Multi-dimensional table length

Tags: php

I have the below array which is going to be larger:

```
$numbers = array(
array(1,2,3,5,9,8,6),
array(1,5,7,2,3,0),
array(2,5,9,25,78,89)
);
```

How do i get the length of the arrays which are in the array?

Comment: Loop through the array and do `count()` on each one?

Comment: Do you need to know the lengths of each individual sub-array, or the max value? `$maxLength = max(array_map('count', $myArray));`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here,

```
<?php
$food = array('fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),
          'veggie' => array('carrot', 'collard', 'pea'));

// recursive count
echo count($food, COUNT_RECURSIVE); // output 8

// normal count
echo count($food); // output 2

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this -**

```
$numbers = array( 
            array(1,2,3,5,9,8,6), 
            array(1,5,7,2,3,0), 
            array(2,5,9,25,78,89)
         );
echo count($numbers);  // Count of outer array ==> 2


$counts = array();
foreach($numbers as $number)
{
    $counts[] = count($number);
}

print_r($counts);  // Array of count of inner
echo array_sum($counts);  // Total Count of inner arrays ==> 19
```